# Django auth login passing empty request to login.html

Tags: authentication, request, django-1.6

On upgrading from Django 1.3 to 1.6, I notice that I no longer have access to the request in 'registration/login.html'.

Because I have a shopping cart on every page (including the login page), this now raises an "AttributeError at /accounts/login/ - 'str'object has no attribute 'session'" because the cart function can't fetch the cart items via request.session.

For reference, here is the inbuilt auth.login function:

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@csrf_protect
@never_cache
def login(request, template_name='registration/login.html',
          redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME,
          authentication_form=AuthenticationForm,
          current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    Displays the login form and handles the login action.
    """
    redirect_to = request.REQUEST.get(redirect_field_name, '')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = authentication_form(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Ensure the user-originating redirection url is safe.
            if not is_safe_url(url=redirect_to, host=request.get_host()):
                redirect_to = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

            # Okay, security check complete. Log the user in.
            auth_login(request, form.get_user())

            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
    else:
        form = authentication_form(request)

    current_site = get_current_site(request)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

This function appears to return a request object via TemplateResponse, but I cannot access it within 'registration/login.html'. If I remove the cart, login works as normal.

As a workaround, I can remove the cart from the login page, but I wonder why this has changed (maybe a security vulnerability?). It seems that somewhere between calling the auth.login function and the login.html page, the request is getting lost. Does anyone know what's happening to the request?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've solved it.

For some reason, my TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py was empty. According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) the default TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS for Django 1.6 should be:

```
("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

Adding this line:

```
'django.core.context_processors.request',
```

to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting makes everything work as expected. Now I'm wondering why the rest of the site was working when TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS was empty! (how were my other pages able to access the request when this wasn't set?)